# Ansible: Sequence range using loop variable

Tags: ansible

I need to create a certain number of systemd unit files based on name and included variable with number of files to create, like:

```
app-name@1.service
app-name@2.service
app-name@3.service

script-name@1.service
script-name@2.service
script-name@3.service
script-name@4.service
```

It works with a nested loop using range function, but I not understand how to use loop variable (item.1.workers) into range() parameters.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    apps:
        - name: app-name
          workers: 3
        - name: script-name
          workers: 5
  connection: local
  tasks:

  - name: test
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.1.name }}@{{ item.0 }}.service"
    loop: "{{ range(1, 3) | product(apps) | list }}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's create the lists of *workers* in the first task and loop with *subelements* in the second task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        apps1: "{{ apps1|default([]) +
                   [{'name': item.name,
                     'workers': range(1, item.workers + 1)|list}] }}"
      loop: "{{ apps }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.name }}@{{ item.1 }}.service"
      loop: "{{ apps1|subelements('workers') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
      msg: app-name@1.service
      msg: app-name@2.service
      msg: app-name@3.service
      msg: script-name@1.service
      msg: script-name@2.service
      msg: script-name@3.service
      msg: script-name@4.service
      msg: script-name@5.service
```